# Tyre damage from hitting a curb

Tags: tires

the other day I hit a curb going about 15 mph, it was more of a light touch so I didn’t bother to go out and check it. Yesterday I noticed a crack in the tire and a piece of the rubber on the side had been chipped off. My question is , does this tyre need to be replaced or is this only cosmetic damage? I was thinking of replacing the front tyres next winter anyway. [image]!

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to this is yes you need a new tire.

In general if the side wall of a tire is damaged by driving over a sharp object at some speed you need to replace the tire,In the side wall of a tire there is only one or two layers of tread and this tread might wery well be damaged or even broken so the tire might suddenly fail,if this where to happen in highway speed it might be fatal to you and or others.